# Opening a msg file into Outlook though JavaScript

Tags: javascript, outlook, msg

I have a msg file stored in a Database and want a user to be able to open outlook from a browser with that file.
Until now a user can only save/open this msg file through that code:

```
window.DownloadFile = function (myFile) {
        var data = myFile.Base64String;
        var filename = myFile.FileName;
        if (clientType === 'Windows') {
            var file = dataURItoBlob(data);
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
        }
        else {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = data;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    }
```

But I want the user to be able to open Outlook with that file.

Thanks in Advance
Lerxx

Answer (score 0):

You can save the .msg file on the disk and then run this file using the following code:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
         MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )  
         function RueMsg()   
         {  
            MyObject.Run("file:///filepath.msg") ;  
        }  

    </script>
```

Due to the fact that Outlook is a singleton, the message will be opened even if it is already running on the system.